# Need explanation of the spinor norm

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, geometry

Wikipedia and Groupprops gave a definition, but they didn't elaborate, so I don't understand, and there aren't cited sources on them.

1. Is there any online sources that have proof on their basic property, such that the spinor norm is well-defined, or that its kernel is the derived subgroup of SO and is normal?
2. Why is it called "spinor" norm, does it have any relationship to spinor?
3. What's its geometrical meaning? I understand that this map is trivial for R and C so "geometrical" meaning my be hard, but hopefully there is something like that for say Q.

Comment: book reviews, Cassels is probably the easiest. https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183546482    \\\\\\  https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183555136

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about an online source, but you can check section 9.3 of Quadratic and Hermitian Forms by Scharlau, there are a reasonable amount of details.

It is called the spinor norm because it is actually naturally defined on the spinor group. Indeed, you have a natural involution $x\mapsto \sigma(x)$ on the Clifford algebra $C(V,q)$ of a quadratic space $(V,q)$ (which is characterized by the fact that it is the identity on $V$), and thus you have a "norm" $N: C(V,q)\to C(V,q)$ given by $x\mapsto x\sigma(x)$. (This may be reminiscent of the quaternion norm.) Then if you restrict  $N$ to the spinor group $\Gamma(V,q)\subset C(V,q)$, you actually get a group morphism $\Gamma(V,q)\to K^*$, which induces the spinor norm $O(V,q)\to K^*/K^{*2}$.

Note that it is not true that the spinor norm is trivial over $\mathbb{R}$; it is trivial for the usual scalar product, but there are other quadratic forms over $\mathbb{R}$, for which the spinor norm need not be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier characterization of the Spinor norm, but it only works for Isogenic quadratic forms in dimension $2$ or $3$. Suppose $Q$ is a quadratic form on $V=K^3$, given by the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Consider the zero locus: $Z(Q)^*=\{v\in V\setminus\{0\}: Q(v)=0\}$. This set has an equivalence relation given by $z_1\sim z_2$ if one of the following conditions is satisfied:
a) $z_1=\lambda z_2$ for a certain $\lambda\in K^{*2}$
b) $-2\langle z_1,z_2\rangle\in K^{*2}$. 

The quotient space $Z(Q)^*/\sim$ is given by:
$$\{[\lambda e_1]: \lambda\in K^*/K^{*2}\}$$
The Spinor norm reflects how $O(V,Q)$ acts on $Z(Q)^*/\sim$.

For the general case, Captain Lama covers it pretty well.

EDIT: This actually has a nice geometric interpretation on $K=\mathbb{R}$. On that field, we can partition $Z(Q)$ into: $$S_1=\{(x,y,z)\in Z(Q): x\leqslant 0, y\geqslant 0\}\\ S_2=\{(x,y,z)\in Z(Q): x\geqslant 0, y\leqslant 0\}$$
Transformations with Spinor norm $-1$ permute between those sets, whereas transformations with Spinor norm $1$ keep those sets intact.

Comment: Actually realize that this actually generates flawlessly to higher dimensions, as long as the Witt index is 1, and Q takes only one value in K*/K^{*2} on the anisotropic part (which is always the case for K=R).